# C++ successfully copying dynamically allocated obj without copy ctor?

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor

I have a class with pointer to char. I am wondering how is it possible that copy construction is possible without explicitly defining copy constructor?

I assume because the object was already allocated, but if so, then why would someone need copy constructors in the first place?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Data {
public:
    explicit Data(const char* newData)
        :size{strlen(newData)},
         data{size ? new char[size] : nullptr}
    {
        std::memcpy(data, newData, size);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Data& rhs) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.size; i++) {
            std::cout << rhs.data[i];
        }
        ost << "\n";
        return ost;
    }

~Data() {
    delete[] data;
}

private:
    std::size_t size;
    char* data;
};

int main() {
    Data data1{"data1"};
    Data data2{data1}; // copy constructor
    std::cout << data1;
    std::cout << data2;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
data1
data1
```

Shouldn't the copy constructor look like that? I am often seeing such examples. But since the default constructor already did that, then when do I actually need to define copy ctor?

```
Data(const Data& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        size = other.size;
        data = new char[size];
        std::memcpy(data, other.data, size);
    }
}
```

By the way, I realize the code introduces some maul practices (e.g. using new instead of smart ptrs, not using string in the first place, etc. - but it's just an exercise).

Comment: You don't need to check `this != &other` in the copy constructor because an object that is not already constructed cannot be the same as the given object (you can't pass what's not already existing). This check is useful in the copy-assignment operator though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, the generation of the [implicitly-defined copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-defined_copy_constructor) is deprecated (for a good reason) if a class has a user-defined destructor, but it is still generated. That copy constructor will just copy `size` and `data`, making a shallow copy, not a deep one. This a road to disaster, because `data` will then be deleted multiple times, when the original object and its copies are destroyed.

For example, if you run your original code under [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), you'll see the following report:

```
==9908== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9908==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9908==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 4 frees, 73,733 bytes allocated
==9908== 
==9908== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9908== 
==9908== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9908== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If you want `Data` to be copyable, you have to provide a deep copy constructor that allocates new storage and copies data into it. The one in your question looks almost (*) fine:

```
==9993== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9993==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9993==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 73,738 bytes allocated
==9993== 
==9993== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9993== 
==9993== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9993== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If you don't need copy construction at all, you can disable its implicit generation by explicitly deleting it:

```
Data(const Data&) = delete;
```

The same is true for copy assignment operator. The [implicitly-defined one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-defined_copy_assignment_operator) will not do what you want. [Don't forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) about it.

(*) Note that `other.data` can be `nullptr`, so you [have to check it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) before copying:

> `void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count);`
>
> If either `dest` or `src` is a null pointer, the behavior is undefined, even if `count` is zero.